# Call backing bean from p:inputText ondblclick

Tags: primefaces

I need to do a double click on a p:inputText inside a p:dataTable so that it will bring me to another page and launch the details. Is it possible to call backing bean method from Primefaces p:inputText ondblclick?

Answer (score 1):

`p:inputText` is a normal `input` in the end, you can use jQuery to register `ondblclick` on it, then you can call a `p:remoteCommand` to reach your bean.

I assume you would have multiple inpuText since you have a [dataTable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableBasic.jsf).

***xhtml***

```xhtml
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{bean.cars}">  
    <p:column headerText="Model">  
        <p:inputText value="#{car.model}" styleClass="dbClickInput" />    
    </p:column>  
</p:dataTable> 

<p:remoteCommand name="callDetailsCommand" 
                 actionListener="#{bean.callDetails()}" />
```

```javascript
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { 
      $('.dbClickInput').dblclick(
          function() {
            callDetailsCommand([{name: 'carModelValue', value: $(this).val()}]);
          }
      );
   });
</script>
```

***Bean***

```java
public void callDetails() {
   FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
   Map map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
   String carModelValue = (String) map.get("carModelValue");
}
```

Hope this helps.